# c++ Output only the max array value and count

Tags: c++

I was comparing the array values in format arr[i] > arr[max]

It outputs all the values which is greater to arr[0].

Can you guys give me tips on how to ouput JUST the greatest value?

Code:

```
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){   
        cout<<"Enter how many pancakes eaten by the Person #"<<i<<" : ";
        cin>>pancake;
        person[i] = pancake;            
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(person[i]>person[i+1]){
            pancakeCount = pancake[i];
            cout<<"The number of most eaten pancakes is "<<pancakeCount<<" by Person#"<<i<<endl;
        }
    }
```

The problem is the output:

Output:

```
    //list of persons and the number of pancakes they ate.
    The number of most eaten pancakes is 10 by Person#7
    The number of most eaten pancakes is 10 by Person#9
```

each time I put the greatest value before the last iteration, it also outputs the last iteration containing the greatest value which is Person#7

I only want the highest value to be the output itself.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense, you use `pancake` without an index in the first loop but then you use `pancake[i]`. You'll need to post some more context. Also you probably want to move the second `cout` line outside of its loop if you don't want it to print every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pancakeCount(0), max_person(0);
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){   
    cout<<"Enter how many pancakes eaten by the Person #"<<i<<" : ";
    cin>>pancake;
    person[i] = pancake;            
}
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    if(person[i]>pancakeCount){
        pancakeCount = pancake[i];
        max_person = i;
    }
}

cout<<"The number of most eaten pancakes is "<<pancakeCount<<" by Person#"<<i<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

split the loops for finding the max and printing the max.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int person[4];
    int pancake, pancakeMax, pancakeMin;
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter how many pancakes eaten by the Person #" << i << " : ";
        cin >> pancake;
        person[i] = pancake;
    }

    //equate to one of the elements to make sure negative numbers are accomodated
    pancakeMax = pancakeMin = pancake;

    // most eaten
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (person[i]>pancakeMax)
        {
            pancakeMax = person[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (person[i] == pancakeMax)
        {
            cout << "The number of most eaten pancakes is " << pancakeMax << " by Person#" << i << endl;

        }
    }

    //least eaten
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (person[i]<pancakeMin)
        {
            pancakeMin = person[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if (person[i] == pancakeMin)
        {
            cout << "The number of least eaten pancakes is " << pancakeMin << " by Person#" << i << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can add a break statement in the second loop if you think your logic needs just one value. Otherwise, right now, it give all occurances of maximum pancakes eaten.

If you are targetting efficiency you can merge the loops like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int person[4];
    int pancake, pancakeMax, pancakeMin;
    int iMax, iMin;
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        cout << "Enter how many pancakes eaten by the Person #" << i << " : ";
        cin >> pancake;
        person[i] = pancake;
    }

    //equate to one of the elements to make sure negative numbers are accomodated
    pancakeMax = pancakeMin = pancake;

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        pancake = person[i];
        if (pancake>pancakeMax){// most eaten
            pancakeMax = pancake;
            iMax = i;
        }
        if (pancake < pancakeMin){//least eaten
            pancakeMin = pancake;
            iMin = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "The number of most eaten pancakes is " << pancakeMax << " by Person#" << iMax << endl;
    cout << "The number of least eaten pancakes is " << pancakeMin << " by Person#" << iMin << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works man. I understand it easily. How about obtaining the least? My code does not output the least value or obtaining the leastValue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your code is wrong algorithim try mine

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{   
  std::cout<<"Enter how many pancakes eaten by the Person #"<<i<<" : ";
  std::cin>>pancake;
  person[i] = pancake;            
}
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  if(person[i]>pancakeCount)
     {
        pancakeCount = person[i];
        personWhoEatMost = i;
     }
}
std::cout<<"The number of most eaten pancakes is "<<pancakeCount
         <<" by Person#"<<personWhoEatMost<<std::endl;
```

Comment: How about obtaining the least number? I am  hours testing for answers, unluckily haven't found one yet.